# Retrieve and display data using Javascript and Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

No matter what I do, I'm unable to display my data. In my HTML I've set up this empty list:

```
    <div class="reviews" style="margin-top: 40px;">
        <ul id="reviews-list"></ul>

    </div>
```

And this is what I have for JS:

```
// load
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "reviews"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    createFormData(doc);
})
const formData = document.querySelector('.reviews');

function createFormData(doc) {
    let div = document.createElement('DIV');
    let title = document.createElement('span');
    let hall = document.createElement('span');
    let content = document.createElement('span');

    title.textContent = doc.data().title;
    hall.textContent = doc.data().hall;
    content.textContent = doc.data().content;

    div.appendChild(title);
    div.appendChild(hall);
    div.appendChild(content);

    formData.appendChild(div);
}
```

Can anyone help?

I tried multiple Youtube videos and other sources to display my database data in a ul, and it either gives errors or nothing happens.

Comment: When something goes wrong, you get errors from firebase. If you don't get errors, then it could be that your collection is empty? Have you ever tried to output that very simple via console.log?

Comment: Yes, data is being added to the database and console.log works until I use my createFormData method, but I'm unsure how to troubleshoot it

Comment: try to put the doc.data() into a constant. const data = doc.data() and use it in your function: data.title etc.

Comment: it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: src_db.collection is not a function

Comment: However, I don't use that in my code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const formData = document.querySelector('.reviews');
createFormData()

async function createFormData() {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "reviews"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const div = document.createElement('DIV');
    const title = document.createElement('span');
    const hall = document.createElement('span');
    const content = document.createElement('span');

    title.textContent = doc.data().title;
    hall.textContent = doc.data().hall;
    content.textContent = doc.data().content;

    div.appendChild(title);
    div.appendChild(hall);
    div.appendChild(content);

    formData.appendChild(div);
  })
}
```